# How does one pronounce "Latinx"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

The word "Latinx" seems to be the English shorthand for saying "Latino and/or Latina", where Latino includes men and Latina includes women.

How does one pronounce "Latinx"?

Comment: (note that the OP in that earlier question specifically asked about **latinx / latin@**).

Comment: @Tonepoet As intended, it would have been a duplicate (per the OP in a comment). As written, it was not a duplicate, and the answer isn't found there.

Comment: Did you research this at all? You should attempt to answer your own question before asking it here, and then explain why you still don't understand it.

Comment: @Mary That sounds counter to the whole purpose of this site, which encourages self-answers and the like.

Comment: @Casey No, one of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that the question cannot be easily answered with a web search or standard references, and the original poster is expected to demonstrate their preliminary research efforts; see [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) in the help center..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's pronounced "La-teen-ex,”** based on these sources:

> The word “Latinx” (pronounced “La-teen-ex”) has been used more and more lately.
>
> ---
>
> [Why People Are Using The Term ‘Latinx’](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/why-people-are-using-the-term-latinx_us_57753328e4b0cc0fa136a159) by [Tarisha Love Ramirez](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/author/tanisha-love-ramirez) and  for [Huffpost](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/)

> Latinx, pronounced "La-teen-ex," includes the numerous people of Latin American descent whose gender identities fluctuate along different points of the spectrum, from agender or nonbinary to gender non-conforming, genderqueer and genderfluid.
>
> ---
>
> [Why We Say Latinx: Trans & Gender Non-Conforming People Explain](http://www.latina.com/lifestyle/our-issues/why-we-say-latinx-trans-gender-non-conforming-people-explain) by [Raquel Reichart](http://www.latina.com/lifestyle/our-issues/why-we-say-latinx-trans-gender-non-conforming-people-explain) for Latina.

Comment: Most of this answer is more suitable as a comment, and if we're going to be sticklers for rules, answering a flagged duplicate that's likely to be closed isn't very helpful in my opinion because the rule exists in part because we aim to have all of the answers in place. While it is true that the old question is closed, it should be argue that the old post should be reopened on meta if you have reason to believe it is provable with facts, references or expertise and hence not P.O.B., and we mostly have the research rule to preempt answers like this.

Comment: @Tonepoet So we're not supposed to answer questions marked duplicate?

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, and isn't noticeably flagged duplicate. In my experience, answering partially duplicate questions often strengthens the SX community because many "duplicate" questions aren't true duplicates--they're just similar. Regardless, this discussion belongs in a meta post.

Comment: It wasn't covered on this SX site, but it is topical. That's reason enough to ask it here.

Comment: It's somewhat of a discretionary call because sometimes questions are falsely identified as duplicates. Generally, we are not supposed to answer questions which should be closed though. If 5 people with over 3000 rep. vote to close a question, no new answers will be taken until it is reopened. Also, it is not just the duplicate close reason I proposed, but also the lack of research you insisted upon.  Granted, there are quite a few caveats to that general rule, but it's too complicated to explain in a comment. Usually, I'd give citations, but I'm having trouble finding the meta-post I saw.

Comment: @Tonepoet: Unfortunately, people closed the duplicate (as "primarily opinion-based", which is totally bogus), so Mary couldn't have posted this nice answer there.